# Include multiple .env files in one Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, environment-variables

When it comes to loading environment variables in a Makefile most answers point to doing this:

```
include .env.dev
export $(shell sed 's/=.*//' .env.dev)
```

where `.env.dev` is a file containing my environment variables, for example:

```
FOO=bar
SQL_DATABASE=mydb_dev
```

However, I have two `.env` files, one for production and one for development. It does not seem possible to place this `include` command inside a `make` command, nor a variable. What I would ideally like is to have a `Makefile` along the lines of:

```
include config/.env.django.dev
export $(shell sed 's/=.*//' config/.env.django.dev)

serve-dev:
    - npm run dev

build-prod:
    - npm run build
```

where running `make serve-dev` will first load in variables from the file `.env.dev`, but running `make build-prod` will first load in variables from the file `.env.prod`. Many of the variables have the same key but different values, so I can't load in both together.

What would be a good approach here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two options:

- Put the variable-loading code inside of a recipe, wrapped in `$(eval ...)`.

  The downside is that you won't be able to access those variables before entering a recipe, if you need them there for some reason.

  ```
  serve-dev:
      $(eval include include .env.dev)
      $(eval export $(shell sed 's/=.*//' .env.dev))
  ```
- Wrap the variable-loading code in something like `ifneq ($(filter serve-dev,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),)` ... `endif`.

  This will make the variables accessible anywhere, put it will only work if the target was specified with a command-line flag, as opposed to being built as a dependency of some other target.

  ```
  ifneq ($(filter serve-dev,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),)
  include config/.env.django.dev
  export $(shell sed 's/=.*//' config/.env.django.dev)
  endif
  ```

Comment: Any chance of adding an example of what you mean? I can't quite get it based on that. I'm fine with doing things within the context of a single recipe.

Comment: Nice! that's it :) Thanks @HolyBlackCat